# Why do electrons cross the collector-base junction and does current flow between collector and emitter?

Tags: transistors, bjt

1. If the base-emitter junction of an NPN transistor is forward biased, electrons flow from emitter to base. If the collector-base junction is reverse biased, how can they cross it?
2. If I connect the emitter to negative and collector to positive terminal of a battery and don't connect any battery to base-emitter junction, what would happen? Will electrons cross the emitter-base junction? What will stop them?

Comment: what does it say in the spec sheets (see Icbo)?

Comment: Base is like a switch between Collector and Emitter. If a small current flows through the Base then a larger current (Ic=beta x Ib) can be driven between the Collector and Emitter.

Answer (score 4):

1) The essence of an NPN transistor is that it is **not** just 2 PN diodes in anti series (like NP - PN ) but an NPN structure where the P-layer is **quite thin**.

So what happens is that the electrons coming from the emitter (at some speed) while traveling through that **very thin** base, have a large chance of **going too far** and ending up in the **collector**. This happens despite the base-collector junction being reverse biased.

The thing to remember: thin base !

Also, the doping in the base is also such that the base cannot "catch" (recombine) all the electrons so many electrons make it "safely" through the base without recombining (with the holes in the base) and end up in the collector. I hope you realize that having a thin base region helps as well.

2) You mean, leave the base floating.

I only discus the **majority** carrier currents here. There is also a much smaller **minority carrier current**, see [this question and the answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124679/how-icbo-gets-amplified-to-iceo-in-bjt-when-base-is-open) Since the effect of this is much smaller, I ignore it here.

When the base is floating, the Emitter-base junction **cannot** come into **forward mode**. There would then be no electric field to accelerate the electrons from the emitter so they cannot make it into the collector.

So the NPN will not conduct (between collector and emitter) in this case as the electrons from the emitter cannot make it to the collector as their energy is not sufficient. They need the base to be at a higher potential (the base-emitter junction must be in forward mode) in order to accelerate/gain energy to make it into the collector.

Comment: so what about Icbo? (minority carriers)

Comment: This seems to answer that: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124679/how-icbo-gets-amplified-to-iceo-in-bjt-when-base-is-open

Comment: Will the negative terminal of battery not push the electrons in emitter to cross emitter base junction? ( in the absence of any forward bias applied to emitter base junction )

Comment: @rock Yes but not with enough force (actually: not enough voltage difference relative to the positive node) to force the electrons through. If you increased the voltage at some point **breakthrough** will occur and the current does start to flow. But that is "non standard" operation, we usually want to avoid this.

Comment: FakeMoustache I want to study the working of transistors and other electronic devices from scratch. can you refer me some good books?

Comment: The *The Art of Electronics by Paul Horowitz* is often advised and a good start. But do look at other books. There is no single book to recommend. Also, a book I like might not work for you. Just start by reading anything you have access to but stop reading if it is not what you seek/need/want and then go on to the next book.